# Как изменить значение значение по адресу в exe файле C#

Tags: winforms, c#-7.0

Нужно изменить значение 1 байта по адресу 0x0004B9CB на 07 (изменение hex редактора) в exe-файле. Пробовал по совету с англицкого стака

```
BinaryWriter fileWriter = new(File.Open($"{GetGameDir()}rungame.exe", FileMode.Open));
fileWriter.BaseStream.Position = 0x4B9CB;
fileWriter.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("7"));
fileWriter.Close();
fileWriter.Dispose();
```

В итоге он пишет 34. Что я делаю не так и как можно исправить?

Comment: `.Write(0x07)`?

Comment: Спасибо, да. Это спасло!